# Git uses invalid author name in commits

Tags: windows, git, ssh

When i commit git uses not company mail but my personal, which i use in chrome, i do commits using ssh URL and ssh key contains correct mail address, in git lab commits are also under my name but when i open commit author there is my personal URL with nick name. Usually i commit using intellij idea but same result with console commands

I have already reinstalled git and replaced ssh key with new one but it still use my personal nick as author.

So how can i change author of new commits, so it'll be by default correct?
i don't want to write console commands with author argument every time i commit.

OS windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your **Git config file** with required Name and Email Id.

Comment: Found this config in tortoisegit settings, don't remember when i input my mail while installing git :/

Comment: open git bash..run  this command "git config user.mail" . It will show your mail id

Answer (score 2):

You can update your config file from Git Bash:

```
git config --global user.name "[Your name]"
git config --global user.email [email address]
```

This will set a global username and email.

To check your current settings:

```
git config --list
```